# JMeter hangs while running on docker container

Tags: docker, jmeter

I just followed this [readme](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter) and able to build the image but when test.sh is invoked, I see logs up to line no.32 in [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) i.e,
`echo "jmeter ALL ARGS=${EXTRA_ARGS} $@"`

After this nothing happens.

[image]

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get into the container by invoking [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command like this:

```
docker exec -it your-container-name-or-id /bin/bash
```

once done you can take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and/or inspect operating logs to see what's going on under the hood.

It might be the case that your container doesn't have network/Internet access hence it cannot reach this `www.m5.nl` host.

By default JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers don't have any timeout which means that JMeter will wait for the response **forever** (unless there are any timeouts defined in JDK/OS)

So it might be a good idea to define reasonable timeouts, the settings live under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices), this way the timeouts will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers)

[image]

It's also a good idea to check your [Docker engine logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/logs/), it might be the case Docker backend doesn't have enough memory to serve 6GB of RAM requested by the JVM

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the resonse.
I am using colima on mac, and starting colima with following command,
```colima start --memory 8 --arch x86_64 --cpu 4 --disk 100```
And the tests are junit sampler, there is timeout set for http client.